# How to change dynamic title in view page source?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have default, `$document[0].title = "My App"`. In html, `<title ng-bind="title"></title>` it will display on tab header as a `"My App"`

When you right click on page and showing "view page source" then, it still display `<title ng-bind="title"></title>` instead of `<title>My App</title>`

[image: snapshot for view page source]

Comment: Just to confirm. It's showing the title properly in the browser tab, but you are not seeing it in the view source?

Comment: yes. And I want it for google SEO purpose.

Answer (score -2):

Set it on $rootScope:
In your configuration

```
app.run(($rootScope) => {
  $rootScope.title = 'your title';
});
```

Then in your controller/directives controller

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('something', ($rootScope, $scope) => {
    $rootScope.title = 'Dashboard';
  });
```

Comment: That won't affect the source code, only the DOM after it is modified by JavaScript.

Answer (score -2):

You can't. View source shows **the source code**. Changes you make to the DOM with JavaScript are not part of the source code.

The element inspector will show a view of the live DOM, but the source code will always be the source code.